Circles of light during rendering Cycles
Circles of light during rendering Cycles, I can't figure out how to fix this circle. I have five other lights, and this one also used to work well before, but I accidentally moved it and it stopped shining normally.

Apart from deleting, there is not much to say here. Your question lacks of any information about light properties, visibility settings etc.

Best option is to delete the light and recreate one, being careful to position it properly.
